# Javascript getting users current locations in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

all I could find on the internet was to get the users location and display it on the their google maps. I am trying to make a submission form with google maps. So users pick a location in google maps and it would have a submit button where it sends the location that they have picked.

Couldn't find anything like that. I know that Geocoding is not what I need because it only converts an address to coordinates whereas I need to get coordinates from the API itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3vgNN/2/

Get click coordinats like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) { 
        alert( e.latLng.lat() + e.latLng.lng() );
        //optionally mark the location
        markLocation( e.latLng );
});
```

If you wanted you could mark the location also:

```
var marker = false;

function markLocation( userLocation ){

if( ! theLocation ){

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLocation,
        map: map,
        title:"Chosen location"
    }); 

}else{

    //update the marker position if it's already been set
    marker.setPosition( userLocation );

}

}
```

Good luck!

Comment: That works really nice but I don't want to click anything on the maps. I want to click an HTML button that would call a javascript function that would get the coordinates.

Comment: So you want them to pick a location and then click another button to get the coordinate of that selected location?